# Normal error: One vertex shares all normals of an object

Tags: 3d-view, shaders, normals, error

I was working with my .blend file on a new computer and when I opened the file, for some reason the viewport couldn't show the shaded surfaces of the objects, only the outlines in object mode. I have tried all viewport shaders (wireframe, solid, material preview etc.), but it didn't render the objects.
[image: Unshaded objects in object mode]

I think I found the problem When I turned on split normals. As you can see, all split normals seem to be concentrated in one single vertex. I have no idea how this came to be but I have worked on it from another computer with version 2.82a, uploaded it to Google Drive and then downloaded and opened it on a new computer. The Blender version was the same, but it did shade correctly on that computer so I assume this error happened during upload. I have not used any custom normals on the objects.
[image: Objects in edit mode]
[image: Single object with defunct normals]

I tried 'recalculate outside' already, but so far this doesn't recalculate my split normals. I would greatly appreciate it if someone has an idea how to fix my normals.

EDIT: The face normals are all at one place, too. I created the .blend file with 2.93.1, so it might be a version problem. I forgot to mention that.
[image: Split normals and face normals]

Comment: Never experienced that, so I can't reproduce it instantly... what about clearing all split normals? _Object Data Properties_ > _Geometry Data_ > _Clear Custom Split Normals Data_.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I forgot to mention that I created the .blend file in 2.93.1 on my home PC. I tried what you suggested in 2.82a on a different computer and it didn't really work. When I just worked on it in the newer version the normals weren't concentrated to one vertex anymore. It seems to be a version problem then.